# use powershell to add Edge Extension

Tags: powershell, registry, microsoft-edge

I have a .CRX file  (ex: lajjpilliikppcbaghjehndpfdiiphbe_main.crx) that I would like to manually load onto an Edge extension...   Powershell is preferable tool for me as a silent installer.  I can manually do this by dragging the file onto the Edge Extension menu screen, but I can't expect users to do this, and need to have this on command script during signon to the system.

Articles I've found thus far seem to point to adding Registry values to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Edge\Extensions.  However adding the key did not trigger Edge to recognize the package.

Any suggestions are appreciated.. Rob...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to distribute an extension through local file path, it's impossible. According to [this doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/external_extensions/#prereqs), you can know that *Windows and Mac installs must come from Chrome Web Store, and install external extensions through local crx files are not allowed*. Edge is based on chromium so it's the same. That's for security reasons.

If the extension has been published to Microsoft Edge Add-ons website, you can distribute the extension using registry according to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/alternate-distribution-options#use-the-windows-registry-windows-only). For example, if I want to add [this extension](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/dark-reader/ifoakfbpdcdoeenechcleahebpibofpc) to Edge silently, first I need to find the extension id in the end of the page url. Then edit the registry setting like below:

[image]

Comment: strange.. I have an software package (Pega Robotics) that I install on a machine via a setup script.   The install adds an extension from local install directory to both Edge and Chrome.   No webstore was involved.  nothing special was done to my knowledge.   And the extensions do not exist on the web stores...  Anybody else have suggestions?

Comment: According to your description, I wonder that if the extension is hidden. If the extension is uploaded to Web Store and set [Visibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/publish-extension#visibility) to `Hidden`, it is not discoverable in Web Store. But it does exist in the store and has a link to install. I guess it's still installed from Web Store link instead of from local.